# Add More Button not Working - ScoreBook.java

Tags: java, android, xml, debugging, crash

I am trying to make a scorebook app for Cricket. In the Team1.java class of the app I try to populate teams A and then B. It has an EditText member, where user can type the name of the player and then press the Add More button to add more players into an ArrayList of teamPlayers. The problem is that APPLICATION CRASHES WHEN I PRESS THE ADD MORE BUTTON. The code is highlighted below. Any help would be appreciated.

Team1.java

```html
package ammar.newscorebook;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Team1 extends Activity {
 private String teamName;
 private static ArrayList<String> playerList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
 
 private EditText playerName;
 private TextView playerCount;
 private Button addButton;
 private Button doneButton;
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_populate);
  
  setTeamName();
  setPlayerNames();
  done();
 }

 


 private void setTeamName() {
  // TODO Gets the name from edittext and sets it to a variable
  EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.teamName);
  editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    teamName = arg0.toString();
    
   }

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
     int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
     int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }
   
  });
 }
 
 private void setPlayerNames() {
  // TODO set the player names one by one in the array 
  
   playerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playerName);
   playerCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player_count_textview);
   
   addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_button);
   addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     String s = playerName.getText().toString();
     if(playerName.length() != 0){
      playerList.add(s);
      playerCount.setText(playerName.length());
      playerName.setText(R.string.playername_hint); 
     }
    }
   });
  }
   

 private void done() {
  // TODO Takes to Team2 populate activity
  doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done_button);
  doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Team1.this, Team2.class);
    String text = "Team " + getTeamName() + " created";
    Toast.makeText(Team1.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    startActivity(i);
    
   }
  });
  
 }



 public String getTeamName() {
  return teamName;
 }
 

 public ArrayList<String> getPlayerList() {
  return playerList;
 }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```html
package ammar.newscorebook;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 
 private Button mButton1; 

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  mButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.team1_populate_button);
  mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Team1.class);
    startActivity(i);
    
   }
  });
  
 }


}
```

Here are the two XML files.

activity_main.xml

```html
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/welcome" />
    
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/team1_populate_button"
        android:text="@string/populate_teams" />
    
    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        
        android:id="@+id/match_info_button"
        android:text="@string/match_info_label" />
    
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:id="@+id/start_scoring_button"
        android:text="@string/scorebook" />
    

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_populate.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="5dp">

  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/teamname_label" />

  <EditText android:layout_margin="5dp" android:id="@+id/teamName" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ems="10" android:hint="@string/teamname_hint">

    <requestFocus />
  </EditText>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:text="@string/playername_label" />

  <EditText android:layout_margin="5dp" android:id="@+id/playerName" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ems="10" android:inputType="textPersonName" android:hint="@string/playername_hint" />

  <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Player Count: " />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/player_count_textview" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="0" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">

    <Button style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" android:id="@+id/add_button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/add_button_label" />

    <Button style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" android:id="@+id/done_button" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/done_button_label" />


  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about if you set `playerName.length() == 0` before you initialize the add button?

This might prevent the app from crushing.